# Printing String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here is my code:

```
String[] magic = {"stick", "hat", "witch"};
String magic1 = magic.toString();
String magic2 = Arrays.toString(magic);

System.out.println(magic1);         // this is printing a memory location
System.out.println(magic2);         // this one prints: [stick, hat, witch]
```

What is the difference between `magic1` and `magic2`?

Comment: `magic1` is the the default toString() output of an array. `magic2` is the output of a toString() method in the Arrays class which gets all the elements for you.

Comment: First one is printing out the array magic's Identity Hash Code. Likely looks something like `String@548543fdfds`.

Comment: Except he's not asking how to print an array.

Comment: my question is :  magic1 is referencing a memory location and printing that. then why not magic2 also doing the same thing ?

Comment: Because `Arrays.toString` is not the same method as `toString()`. They are different methods with different purposes that do different things.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are objects, but they don't change (override) its `toString()` method, which means they use default one, inherited from `Object`. If you read [documentation of this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) you will find:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

In your case

- `getClass().getName()` returns `[Ljava.lang.String` which means

  - one dimensional array (because there is only one `[`)
  - of type which full name is `java.lang.String`
- and `Integer.toHexString(hashCode())` returns something like `1db9742` which is hexadecimal form of integer returned by `hashCode()` method.

Now if you take a look at code of  `Arrays.toString(Object[] array)` (`String[]` is considered as `Object[]`)

```
4531  public static String toString(Object[] a) {
4532      if (a == null)
4533          return "null";
4535      int iMax = a.length - 1;
4536      if (iMax == -1)
4537          return "[]";
4539      StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
4540      b.append('[');
4541      for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
4542          b.append(String.valueOf(a[i]));
4543          if (i == iMax)
4544              return b.append(']').toString();
4545          b.append(", ");
4546      }
4547  }
```

you will see that its purpose is to create string build from content of this array. It does this by iterating over all elements and adding their string representation to StringBuilder which is then used to create String which will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a tailored `toString` which makes the output pretty.

What you see in the *first* `toString`  is the memory address . Reason being that the variable-name is just that - a memory address( aka reference ).

Every class inherits toString, and can implement its own.

[See Arrays class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean[]%29)

```
String[] names = {"Bob", "Dad", "Mom"};
String names1 = names.toString();
String names2 = Arrays.toString(names);

System.out.println(names1 );         
System.out.println(names2 );
```

prints out:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@1034bb5
[Bob, Dad, Mom]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. my question is should not be the output be same for both of them ?    why magic2 is not printing the reference then?

Answer (score 0):

Read the doumentation. I have copied the necessary information here.

```
public static String toString(Object[] a)
```

Returns a **string representation of the contents of the specified array**. If the array contains other arrays as elements, they are converted to strings by the Object.toString() method inherited from Object, which describes their identities rather than their contents.

**The value returned by this method is equal to the value that would be returned by Arrays.asList(a).toString(), unless a is null, in which case "null" is returned.**

```
public String toString()
```

Returns a **string representation of the object**. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
The toString method for class Object returns a **string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object**. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```